# How to enlarge VLC control panel interface

Tags: vlc-media-player

I just reformatted my PC and the size of the control panel interface has reverted back to its normal size, which is too tiny since I always stream to my TV. Is there any way to enlarge the control panel interface?

I stream to my TV, and when I fullscreen VLC the control interface becomes "detached" from the player, but before I reformatted my PC the control interface used to be a lot bigger in that context, which was much more practical since my vision is pretty bad.

Computer Specs:
Windows 10
1920 x 1080

TV Specs:
SONY Bravia (KDL-40Z5100)
40"
1920 x 1080

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? What do you want to enlarge?

Comment: @GaneshR. I've added a screenshot. So, I stream to my TV, and when I fullscreen VLC the control interface becomes "detached" from the player, but before I reformatted my PC the control interface used to be a lot bigger which was much more practical.

Comment: Could you give more information about your devices where are u using vlc player? What screen size/ resolution you have? What manafacture? What operating system? etc.

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob i've added more info as you requested. if there's anything else you'd like to know, just ask

Answer (score 0):

You can install a [custom VLC Skin](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/best-vlc-skins-windows-free-download). There are serval with better a better gui and larger contorl panel as MinimalX:
[image]

Comment: is that the only way?? any idea why it would display the default skin control panel much larger before i reformatted my PC??

Comment: @Anthony Do you have a screenshot from your contorl panel when it was larger. Because your screenshot above is the panel size as I know!?!

Comment: unfortunately i don't. i wish i did because the screenshot above is the "normal" size that i'm used to too. i just assumed they had enlarged the default size of the control panel interface since it was much larger the last time i installed it on my PC (before i reformatted).

Comment: also, i love the MinimalX skin but the control panel interface doesn't seem to be any bigger than the default skin's control panel interface :/

Comment: @Anthony There are serval others: https://www.deviantart.com/customization/skins/media/vlcmedia/popular-all-time/?offset=48

Comment: but which skins have larger control panel interfaces or at least which ones allow me to enlarge it? are or the skins simply that, reskins of the current GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Set environment variable `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR` to `1`.

According to [High DPI Displays](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html#high-dpi-support-in-qt) chapter of the QT documentation:

> Qt 5.6 supports cross-platform high-DPI scaling for legacy applications [...] This allows applications written for low DPI screens to run unchanged on high DPI devices. This feature is opt-in, and can be enabled using the following environment variables:
>
> `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR` `[boolean]` enables automatic scaling, based on the monitor's pixel density. This won't change the size of point-sized fonts, since point is a physical measurement unit. Multiple screens may get different scale factors.
>
> `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` `[numeric]` defines a global scale factor for the whole application, including point-sized fonts.

Comment: thanks so much but how do i access the environment variables so that i can change them?

Comment: ohh windows env var. nm. tysm ill will try this. (i came across this just now too)[https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=154097&start=25]

Comment: i wrote this question so long ago. VLC actually scales larger now automatically, but the issue now is that timestamps are cut off on the TV when theyre above 1h haha